# Parallel recursion slower than "sequential" recursion. Am I doing this wrong?

Tags: c#-4.0, recursion, parallel-processing

I am doing some very basic tests to see if using parallel processing in my program would provide any noticable speed boost. So far, I'm confused as to the results. In my test, I'm building a tree structure with a branching factor of 30. First, I do my testing using no parallelism, then I try the same thing using a parallel for loop. Here are my results:

Sequential:

```
Depth: 2 Time: 0.0013964 (900 nodes)
Depth: 3 Time: 0.0053703 (27,000 nodes)
Depth: 4 Time: 0.3994147 (810,000 nodes)
Depth: 5 Time: 14.8306510 (24,300,000 nodes)
Depth: 6 Time: 6:54.4050838 (729,000,000 nodes)
```

Parallel:

```
Depth: 2 Time: 0.0389201 (900 nodes)
Depth: 3 Time: 0.1180270 (27,000 nodes)
Depth: 4 Time: 6:06.2296531 (810,000 nodes)
```

I didn't bother testing further, as I don't see it taking less than 7 minutes by the 6 depth.

I have a Dual Core processor, and while I understand that parallelism has a certain amount of overhead, I throught that it wouldn't be so significant. I have verified that the tree structures genereated in both situations are properly formed to the specified depth with the appropriate number of children (30) at each node.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ParallelRecursion
{
    class TreeStructure
    {
        public TreeStructure(int targetLevel, bool runParallel)
        {
            _root = new TreeNode(targetLevel, runParallel);
        }

        private TreeNode _root; 
    }

    class TreeNode
    {
        public TreeNode(int targetLevel, bool runParallel)
        {
            _runParallel = runParallel;

            _rnd = new Random();
            _score = _rnd.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);

            _level = 0;
            _targetlevel = targetLevel;

            if (_level < _targetlevel)
            {
                if (!_runParallel)
                {
                    _children = new List<TreeNode>();
                    GenerateChildren();
                }
                else
                {
                    _concurrentChildren = new ConcurrentBag<TreeNode>();
                    GenerateParallelChildren();
                }
            }
        }

        public TreeNode(TreeNode treeNode)
        {
            _runParallel = treeNode._runParallel;

            _rnd = treeNode._rnd;
            _score = _rnd.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
            _parent = treeNode;

            _level = treeNode._level + 1;
            _targetlevel = treeNode._targetlevel;

            if (_level < _targetlevel)
            {
                if (!_runParallel)
                {
                    _children = new List<TreeNode>();
                    GenerateChildren();
                }
                else
                {
                    _concurrentChildren = new ConcurrentBag<TreeNode>();
                    GenerateParallelChildren();
                }                
            }
        }

        private bool _runParallel;
        private Random _rnd;
        private int _score;
        private int _level;
        private int _targetlevel;
        private TreeNode _parent;
        private List<TreeNode> _children;
        private ConcurrentBag<TreeNode> _concurrentChildren;

        private void GenerateChildren()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                _children.Add(new TreeNode(this));
            }
        }        

        private void GenerateParallelChildren()
        {
            Parallel.For(0, 30, i => { GenerateChild(); });
        }

        private void GenerateChild()
        {
            _concurrentChildren.Add(new TreeNode(this));
        }
    }
}
```

You can test it using:

```
TreeStructure ts = new TreeStructure(4, true);//TreeStructure(int targetDepth, bool runParallel)
```

I'm hoping that I'm doing something wrong. Is it just that this sort of structure isn't condusive to parallelism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `ConcurrentBag<T>` in one case and `List<T>` in the other does not make it comparing apples-to-apples. Once you replace `List<T>` with `ConcurrentBag<T>` for non-concurrent children, the speed of running both versions becomes more or less the same.

Comment: I've tried testing with both using ConcurrentBag, then with both not having a list of children (just the child's ref to the parent keeping it a tree). In both situations the speed difference was greatly equalized. Still, running parallel to a depth of 6 took twice as long as running sequential. Is there something else that I could be doing wrong?

Comment: @Chronicide There's some difference between running a `for` loop (very efficient) and having a method run a `for` loop for you (less efficient). You can replace the non-parallel `for` loop with `var x = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(n => new TreeNode(this)).ToArray();` for further equalization. I think the rest of the difference comes from starting and ending a massive number of tasks that all compete for the memory allocator.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. So, do you think it's just my lack of understanding arround parallelization that is preventing me from getting any noticable speed gain, or do you think its just that the problem doesn't lend itself to parallelization? (or both... but I wan't to know if you think there is any way to parallelize this that may provide a speed gain...)

Comment: @Chronicide I think the problem itself is tricky to parallelize nicely, because all threads are ultimately competing for the same allocator. Try pre-allocating all nodes, and see if connecting them into a tree going in parallel would be faster than going sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Parallelism wrong, you are launching a new Task to create a single node, that is why the parallel version is slower, because although the TPL doesn't actually create a task for each iteration it still crate a few of them, and creating tasks are expensive in time (not as much as threads).

What you should do is divide and conquer, divide your work, make a task create a bunch of TreeNode and not just one.

Comment: I've tested it where all thirty children are spawned within a single additional thread (instead of spawning a thread per child). This actually made the parallel version nearly twice as slow. Maybe i'm misreading your answer.

Comment: The difference in time is spectacle, because you are using ConcurrentBag and this class have locking mechanisms slowing down the code. That, added to the Task creation overhead can make things slower. Still I would like to see the code witch you are taking the time results, can you post it?

Comment: I did my test again after removing the ConcurrentBag. Now, each child maintains a ref to it's parent, while the parent has no way of tracking it's children. The time difference is far less then it had been, but it's still there. Sequential depth=6: 1:11.821, Parallel depth=6: 2:00.841. For code, I changed the call to GenerateParallelChildren() to use Paralle.Invoke() and in GenerateParallelChildren() I used a simple for(i=0;i<30;i++) loop to create the children. This method is faster than spawning one child per task, but is still slower than just sequential processing.

Comment: Once again the number of Tasks that you are possibly creating is outrageous, just for the kick try to use only 2 Tasks. The biggest problem that you are having here is creating to much useless tasks, more tasks doesn't mean fastest, think on the thread switches that are happening to create all the 729,000,000 nodes. . .